# Creating if-else condition with ArcGIS API for JavaScript combo boxes?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, combo-box

I have an ArcGIS JavaScript API Web App that uses multiple combo boxes.  I would like to create an if-else conditional statement between two fields in my feature layer.  If one field is chosen in combo box one is 1  then combo box three should automatically populate to 3.

Below is my validate function for my request type.

```
 function changeonevent() {
  (dijit.byId("cbRequestType").on('change'), changeonevent (MFValue) {
    if (MFValue == 'Electronic Waste') {
   dijit.byID("cbMFSubType"). set ('value', 'Copy Machine'); 
   } else if MFValue == '...'{
   dijit.by.ID('cbMFSubType').set('value', 'Printer'); 
   }
```

Comment: Please give some context to this question or be more specific. I, for one, am not very sure what you're asking and how your code sample relates to your question. Perhaps you're just looking for the `onChange` event of the Dojo combo box?  http://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dijit_form_ComboBox_onChange

Comment: No, I  have an application where citizens are to choose the type of service that is needed.  I.E. multi-family refuse, I would like a combo box to pre-populate with other fields such as location, curb side, etc....

Comment: This still sounds like using `onchange` event on your combo box will do the trick: `dijit.byId('foo').on('change', function (val) { ... if (val == 1) bar = 3; else bar = 2; ... }`

Comment: I see, I will give this a shot!

Comment: what does bar = 3 indicate here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the concise comment, I can elaborate here. Say `foo` and `bar` are your combo box dijits:

```
dijit.byId('foo').on('change', function (new_value) {
  if (new_value == 'multi_family_refuse') {
    dijit.byId('bar').set('value', 'bar value 1');
  } else if (new_value == '...') {
    dijit.byId('bar').set('value', 'bar value 2');
  } else {
    ...
  }
});
```

if you have a lot of various states, try using `switch` statement instead.

Using your updated example:

```
  dijit.byId("cbRequestType").on('change', function (MFValue) {
    if (MFValue == 'Electronic Waste') {
      dijit.byID("cbMFSubType").set('value', 'Copy Machine'); 
    } else if MFValue == '...'{
      dijit.by.ID('cbMFSubType').set('value', 'Printer'); 
    }
  });
```

Comment: thank you for this @janechii I am having trouble understanding what 'value' indicates.

Comment: ah... the `set` method takes 2 arguments: the attribute you want the set and the value of that attribute. `set('value', '...')` is equiv to `setValue('...')`.

Comment: I see, thanks again, please see my updated code sample, I am receving an error which notes an unexpected token at line 2 after (MFValue) {.

Comment: see my updated answer. you're running into some syntax issues, which is beyond the scope of this question, but I hope with the example, you'll get the idea. The word `function` there is not a placeholder, but a required keyword to define an anonymous function. Do not change that.

Comment: i really appreciate this @jamechii

Comment: @GeoffreyWest if this answer helped, don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the grey tick mark next to the vote up/down buttons on the left

Comment: Although this was a good work around it proved unsuccessful due to the limitations of the API and accessing feature layers, ultimately it would require a query of a subtype which is not handled by the API.