# Creating if-else statement for two combo boxes in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have an ArcGIS JS API application where I have an "origin" combo box that must be populated for request type, in the following series of combo boxes I would like for a value to be chosen based on the 1st value.

If I have an e-waste item chosen in my request type box, I would like for the second series of boxes to contain an e-waste product before the request can be submitted. This holds true for the other request type values and the following series.

My initial code which does not allow a request to be submitted unless a value is chosen in the request type box is;

```
function ValicateRequestData() {
if (dijit.byId("cbRequestType").getValue() == "") {
    ShowSpanErrorMessage("spanServiceErrorMessage", messages.getElementsByTagName("spanErrorMsgType")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    return false;
}

if (dijit.byId("cbRequestType").getValue() == "") {
    ShowSpanErrorMessage("spanServiceErrorMessage", messages.getElementsByTagName("spanErrorMsgType")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    return false;
}
```

The above box populates with items such as bulky items, e-waste, etc.

I would then like a second box "cbMFEWASTE" to have  a value required if e-waste is chosen in the above box before a request is submitted...

my application is based on the ArcGIS Public Info Center JS API App
http://localgovtemplates2.esri.com/publicinfocenter/

Comment: For anyone interested in answering this question, it looks like the relevant JS file is here: https://github.com/Esri/public-information-center/blob/master/js/serviceRequest.js#L810

Comment: See also: [How to create an if else condition with ArcGIS JavaScript API combo boxes?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116343/how-to-create-an-if-else-condition-with-arcgis-javascript-api-combo-boxes) and [How to link two combo boxes in ArcGIS JavaScript API](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116769/how-to-link-two-combo-boxes-in-arcgis-javascript-api)

Answer (score 1):

If your question is:

> How do i check for the condition where one particular combobox has a
>   value set and a second does not?

then the code would look something like this...

```
if (dijit.byId("cbRequestType").getValue() != "" && dijit.byId("cbRequestType").getValue() == "")
  //throw your error
```

if not, please elaborate.  i agree with @blah238 that given your current explanation, the second question you've posted is a duplicate of the first.